# How to stop calling a delayed function if some other event happens in that period?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After a certain event happens, I have this function (rightMenu) that triggers with 1.5s delay. However, my challenge is to figure out how to check if the leftMenu is called **during** this period then stop the setTimeout function to call the rightMenu.

```js
var leftMenu = function() {
  // some code here
}

var rightMenu = function() {
  // some code here
}

$('#leftMenu').on('click', function() {
  leftMenu();
})

$('#rightMenu').on('click', function() {
  rightMenu();
})


if (...) {
  leftMenu();
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    rightMenu();
  }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Flag of some kind should be useful. Set it in one function, check in another.

Comment: WHy can't you just toggle a class on the opposite menu so user can see it's not available? A better description of expected behavior might help. There are lots of ways to do this

Comment: According to the question right click triggers with 1.5s delay. So flag should be set in the function that is delaying the trigger not in actual handler. So we need the code which is delaying the trigger. I guess that is a better place to put some logic?

Comment: @charlietfl I agree, there are so many different hacks I could come up with to achieve this goal but I want to know what the best practices are in this type of scenarios.

Comment: Not sure why you call them hacks... it's just business logic. Also not clear what your expectations are. Just using flags isn't going to identify anything to user. Also not sure what your preference is since you provided 2 scenarios. So you can get lots of answers and only a few fit what you really need. Can think of probably 10 ways to do this ....using callbacks, toggling classes, canceling timers, using promises,setting flags, hiding controls etc

Comment: @charlietfl So I edited the question to make it clearer. And I just learned about Flag variables :)

Comment: @charlietfl I guess my question is how to check something during a certain time period. e.g. setTimeout triggers after 1.5s. Is there any way to check something during this period?

Comment: This seems like a good place for the use of promises.

Comment: @charlietfl while they're definitely fine javascript implementations, making clojures purely for the purpose of checking some global variable is kinda hacky. You can do it, but it's not necessarily the most broadly accepted way.

Comment: Hey @Saeed, why did you include your jQuery event handlers? Doesn't really seem like they're relevant to the question.

Comment: @Wade ummm if they are, then how come you used them in your answer?

Comment: @Wade what closures and what global variables are you referring to? I don't see where I mentioned either

Comment: @charlietfl if you're using a flag variable, that's a global. Whenever you access a variable outside of a functions scope it creates a closure, no?

Comment: @Saeed because I didn't know what they were for and I didn't want to confuse you even more haha. You can just put the code that you'd put in your function that's called in your jQuery event inside of leftMenu instead though, it's kinda unnecessary to wrap it in a function

Comment: @Wade there are lots of ways to set a flag that aren't global. Not sure where that idea comes from. Nothing declared locally within `document.ready` for example is global ... setting as property of an element is not global... setting property of a config object is not global ... need more?

Comment: @charlietfl so you're going to inject an options object everywhere? Accessing document creates a closure. Accessing anything outside of your function scope creates a closure. Unless you shadow document, accessing it directly from within a function creates a closure, not sure what you mean by "declared locally".

Comment: @Wade you seem to have the concept of `creates closure` completely backwards. A function creates closure of the local variables it contains. Accessing a variable within the scope above a function is not `creating a closure`. I really don't understand what you are trying to say. I don't see how anything I've suggested above would be any different than the solution you provided in your answer

Comment: @charlietfl read this article and see if it helps explain what I mean:
http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

Comment: @charlietfl from a more reputable source: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

closures are functions that are able to examine the environment in which they were called, and because functions do not have access to any variables besides those declared in its scope (meaning no global variables), that means if you do access a global variable, it makes that function into a closure. This is my understanding, and I went back to make sure I haven't been wrong all along, but based on these sources I'm pretty sure my definition is sound.

Comment: @Wade irregardless you have my comments all convoluted into something far more complex and out of context with whatever I said in the first place. If you want to show me your interpretation of what you think is hacky ... in code...feel free but nothing that was mentioned was unusual

Comment: @charlietfl the point is that just because you can do something a multitude of ways, it does not mean that all, or even many, of those ways are generally accepted.

Comment: @Wade what specifically are you focused on? Show me in code. I mentioned some general concepts.... I think you misinterpreted them

Comment: @charlietfl I am curious about your definition of closures though. Do you have a reference I could read? It seems the two I posted (one of which is MDN, who I'd say is quite reputable) agree with my point of view that the child function that takes a snapshot of its environment is the closure, not the parent function that the child is defined in.

Comment: @Wade forget about defintions for now... you brought all this `global` and closures into a discussion where they weren't even relevant to comments I made in the first place ... show me what you think is hacky in the comments...in a code demo

Comment: @charlietfl sure. In this example (under my definition of closures), childFunction is a closure. I was just talking about setting flags at a global level, which a couple people mentioned, but I'm not a huge fan of because it's using unnecessary memory. Just my opinion, but at this point I want to know if my view on this is even correct haha
```
function a () {
  var b = 2;
  function childFunction() {
    return b + 2;
  }
return childFunction;
}
var test = a();
```

Comment: @charlietfl I guess specifically I was talking about the setting flags and toggling classes. Maybe I misunderstood though. For both of those, wouldn't you be required to either inject either the settings or classes everywhere you want to use them, or create a closure when you call your functions?

Comment: @wade you have just been overthinking things too much. There are clsses on html elements ... not just  classes written in programming languages. A flag can be a simple variable no more complex than the way you stored an interval reference in a variable ... and not all variables are global depending on the scope they are declared in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking, but you can clear intervals. For example:

```
function asyncFun() {
    // some code
}

setTimeout(asyncFun, 5000); // this will run after 5 seconds


var asyncHandle = setTimeout(asyncFun, 10000);

clearTimeout(asyncHandle); // this cancels the function call
```

I feel like this is what you're asking...

---

If not, the other interpretation that I have is you want to temporarily remove the event handler from the `#leftmenu` and `#rightmenu` when you're in the other menu. To do this, you can clear event handlers in jQuery with `$("#rightmenu").off("click")`. This function is basically the opposite of `.on`. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/). Good luck!

---

Yet another possible fix to your code:

```
/*
initialize your variable here. Technically doesn't change anything 
because of hoisting, but I'm guessing based on your question you
haven't learned that yet.
*/
var callingRight; 
var leftMenu = function() {

  // some code here
}

var rightMenu = function() {
  // some code here
}

$('#leftMenu').on('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(callingRight); // clear the timeout on your global variable here.
  leftMenu();

})

$('#rightMenu').on('click', function() {
  rightMenu();
})


if (...) {
  leftMenu();
} else {
  callingRight = setTimeout(function() { // assign this setTimeout to your global variable
    rightMenu();
  }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: you should call `clearTimeout` instead of `clearInterval` just to prevent confusion

Comment: @Wade could you please elaborate on your answer? What 10s delay is for? I guess I am looking for way to clear the timer for rightMenu if the leftMenu is clicked in the delay period.

Comment: The 10s delay is to simulate your delay. The point is that if you have a setTimeout, and you assign it to a variable, then you can use `clearTimeout` to cancel the function call.

Comment: Honestly, it's super unclear what your code is doing, and when you want your functions to do or be called (at least for me). Just updated my answer with yet another possible answer, but I still don't know what you're trying to do, even in principle.

Comment: @Wade thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to understand your question haha.